# r - hist function aggregates "zero" and "1" values into one bin.

Tags: r, histogram

I'm getting crazy with hist() function. I have a dataset as follows:

```
table(data)

0  1  2  3  4  5  7  8 
85  7  3  4  6  1  2  1
```

So I expect that `hist(data, labels=TRUE)` returns me a histogram with 9 bins, one for the zeros, one for ones, etc. and with a value over each bin. But it aggregates the 0s and 1s and after one day of search on google, I still cannot figure out how I can fix it. I also tried to declare the number of bins like `hist(data, breaks=c(0,8))` but nothing.
As an alternative, I tried with `histogram` of the `lattice` package, and it works fine... but I cannot figure out how to have the value of each bin displayed...
Can you help me either way (having the right number of columns with `hist()` or having bins values displayed with `histogram()`)?
thanks so much.

Comment: Try `hist(data,right=F)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hist(...)` uses right-closed intervals by default. You can change this using the `right=...` argument.

```
x <- c(0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  8)
y <- c(85,  7,  3,  4,  6,  1,  2,  1)
z <- rep(x,times=y)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(z,right=T, main="Right closed")
hist(z,right=F, main="Left Closed")
```

[image]

Here's the equivalent in `ggplot`, which IMO is a bit clearer.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(z), aes(x=factor(z))) + 
  geom_histogram(fill="lightgreen", color="grey50")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your great explanation! I like ggplot2 better :) Do you know I can put the value of the bars on top of each bar (like the hist(data, labels=TRUE) case)?